# When testing instance method in RSpec my empty array argument is not being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

```
  describe "changes shopping array length" do
subject { described_class.new.change_array_length(group: [], num: 2) }
it "by responding to a method with arguments" do
  expect(subject).to respond_to(:change_array_length).with(2).arguments
end
```

This is what I have written so far. However, when I run the test I get:

```
Failure/Error:
   def change_array_length(group, num)
     group << num
   end
 
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

I removed the num argument and the number of arguments goes down to 0 so it's not reading the empty array.

I've just started learning testing with a course using Ruby not RoR so let me know if I have this slightly wrong for testing the method with arguments!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on expectation to verify [respond_to](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/respond-to-matcher), `subject` should be instance of described class not the the method call.

```
describe "changes shopping array length" do
  subject { described_class.new }
  it "by responding to a method with arguments" do
    expect(subject).to respond_to(:change_array_length).with(2).arguments
  end
end
```

Also one more thing based on your method definition, method does not seem to used named arguments, but when you are calling in subject you are passing as named arguments which @Aarthi mentioned in her answer.

Comment: Oh okay, so if I wanted to say check the group being passed into the method was empty... How would I test for that?

Appreciate the help both of you =)

Comment: @Tigiras https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments This rspec doc will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
subject { described_class.new.change_array_length([], 2) }
```

You used named arguments which will be considered as a hash(single argument). Pass like an unnamed argument as defined in the method.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work. It now gives an error:

     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to respond_to(:change_array_length).with(2).arguments
       expected [2] to respond to :change_array_length with 2 arguments.

The way I originally had it reads it as at least 1 argument?